# Find when application data clear from context?

Tags: android, android-context

In my application i am storing some data in application context.My application data is clear from context when i opened 4 to 5 other applications.Is there any way to find when my application data clear from context.Is it possible.Thanks

Comment: Save your data to the file system or into a DB. Keeping it around in memory does only work until the application is evicted.

Comment: Yes we can store but is there any way to know clear data from context ?

Comment: You know that after it has happened because the data is no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

You application context is available to you only when you are using your application, if you leave it will goes for garbage collection.

Background process limit on android-

> If you own a device that is lacking in processing power and memory, you can use this feature to limit the number of background process that can run between 0 and 4 processes.

To change your device process limit-

1. Go to Android device ‘Settings’
2. Go to ‘Developer options’
3. Enable Developer option by sliding to the right.
4. You get a warning pop-up message. Click on OK.
5. Scroll down, under ‘Apps’ tap on ‘Limit background processes’.
6. Another pop-up appears and this is where you can limit background processes. ‘Standard limit’ will be selected by default. You have an option to select one of the six options.

From [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html#)-

> By default, every application runs in its own Linux process. Android starts the process when any of the application's components need to be executed, then shuts down the process when it's no longer needed or when the system must recover memory for other applications.

You need to use [SharedPref](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to shave your application data.

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
```